# Move datamodel to new project

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have re-created my iphone app project from scratch.  I added my source and datamodel files into the new project.  I have the new project compiling and working.

Now I notice that the app created by my new project is not 'compatible' with my old app.  If I have an existing database on the device/simulator, the new app does not recognize the datamodel, it thinks things have changed.  I get errors:'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'Event'

How do I properly move my datamodel from old project to new project in a way that everything still works?  I have been simply adding in the projectName.xcdatamodelId source files and compiling.  Is there something else that I need to do?

At first I thought that this was happening because I had renamed the files to match the new project name, but I have tried without renaming and am seeing the same problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

**UPDATE:**
OK, maybe it was the renaming.  I cleaned up and rebuilt fresh and it seems to be working again.  It looks like the first time I tried the failure messed things up on the existing database. Can anyone confirm that renaming is problematic, or explain how this can be done correctly?

Comment: good question, I'm waiting on the reply for this one too

Comment: I've tried this many time and renaming the core data modal has always given me the exact error you got.